# In python efficiently serialize set of integers

Tags: python

is there a preexisting function to serialize a set of integers in a efficient and compact form using the 'bitmap' data structure? I am aware of pickle. but it seems it serializes to a verbose string. I need something that will use as little space as possible

Comment: `struct.pack` is about as compact as you can get without getting into things like Huffman encoding.

Comment: how large a set are you considering ? Have you looked at the struct module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

googled some more and the answer seems like the bitarray module
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray

actually, the right answer is intset
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intset/1.0.0